# MySQL: trigger/delimiter without SUPER

Tags: mysql, permissions, triggers

Attempting to run this SQL:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER crypt_f
BEFORE INSERT ON c_data_test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE c_data_test
SET f_id = ENCRYPT(f_id, 'key');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Gives this error:

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

We are not allowed SUPER access from our host. How can I create this trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to ask the DBA of your host to run the trigger create statement for you. The newest versions of MySQL allows non SUPER users to create triggers (MySQL 5.1.6 and greater). However if binary logging is on you will still need SUPER privileges.

So first, double check the version of MySQL running, and if its MySQL 5.1.6 or greater and binary logging is turned off, request the TRIGGER privilege from the hosts DBA, otherwise you would have to ask the DBA to create the trigger for you.